# Custom email layout handle for custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, php, email

I have created a custom module, In which I am sending email to customer. email is working fine but I have created a layout handle in `layout/test.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <my_name_is_hello>
        <block type="core/template" name="hello"  template="test/sales/items.phtml"></block>
    </my_name_is_hello>
</layout>
```

This is my content in `test/sales/items.phtml`

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Now I have called layout handle in my email template file `hello.phtml` using both method but file is not getting called.

```
{{layout handle="my_name_is_hello"}}
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='test/sales/items.phtml'}}
```

Please can anybody suggest me if I am doing something wrong or any solution

Comment: You file name have to layout/my_name_is_hello.xml

Answer (score 0):

First add the layout of the block in **sales.xml** in layout section file.

```
<my_name_is_hello>
    <block type="core/template" name="hello"  template="test/sales/items.phtml"></block>
</my_name_is_hello>
```

Than after use the below line in the email template

```
 {{layout handle="my_name_is_hello"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `config.xml` add this :

```
<global>
    ...
     <template>
         <email>
             <yourRooter_email_email_template translate="label" module="your module">
                 <label>custom email</label>
                 <file>custom_email.html</file>
                 <type>text</type>
             </yourRooter_email_email_template>
         </email>
     </template>
    ...
</global>
```

Then go to : `app/locale/language_ISO/template/email/custom_email.html` then add your block:

`{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='test/sales/items.phtml'}}`